# How do I execute my Visual Test project in the build output folder for Azure Devops Visual Studio Test task

Tags: azure, unit-testing, azure-devops, devops

On my local machine the Unit tests run successfully on the deployment folder. They fail when run on a local test deployment folder as some files are missing.

Is there a way to have the tests run on the deployment folder (as opposed to test deployment folder) when being run on Azure Devops Visual Studio Test task.

Comment: What do you mean by saying deployment folder?

Comment: Hi, is there any update for this issue?

Answer (score 0):

> How do I execute my Visual Test project in the build output folder for
>   Azure Devops Visual Studio Test task

Since the issue you got came from missing assemblies. You should check how you configure the `Test files` and `Search folder`:

[image]

For yaml: check `testAssemblyVer2` and `searchFolder` inputs.

According to your description, the VSTS test task is in classic release pipeline or multi-stage yaml pipeline.

If the build outputs you mean come from build task in build pipeline, consider using [Download artifact task](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/artifacts/pipeline-artifacts?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml) first to download the build outputs.

And If the build outputs come from build task in same pipeline, or from local machine. Just make sure the Search folder is set correctly to locate the assemblies.